# Use asterisk as client to act as a soft phone

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I have an account with vonage and I am able to make phone calls from my computer entering the following information into my soft phone ([zoiper](https://www.zoiper.com/en)):

[image]

When entering that information (domain,usrename and password) into my soft phone settings I am able to make phone calls and also receive. **At this point everything works great**

**Now my question is** how can I make outbound calls from asterisk using that same information that I got from vonage? I would like my soft phone to connect to asterisk, then asterisk making the outbound call.

**This is what I have tried:**

This is how my sip.conf looks like:

```
[general]
   tcpenable=yes
   etc.....

 [SoftPhone1]
   secret=MySecretPassword
   context=MainContext
   type=friend
   disallow=all
   transport=udp,tcp
   etc...

 [vonage-test]
   type=peer
   host=sip-55623.accounts.vocalocity.com
   secret=*********
   username=VH283034
   disallow=all
   allow=ulaw
   transport=udp,tcp
   dtmfmode=auto
   insecure=invite
```

and on my extensions.conf

```
[general]
  static=yes
  etc...

[MainContext] ; this is the context where SoftPhone1 is registered
  exten => 100,1,NoOp(Testing to see if we can make outbound call) ; just write to the console
  same => n,Dial(SIP/3051234567@vonage-test) ; make phone call to 3051234567
  same => n,Hangup()


  etc...
```

when I dial extension 100 the call never goes to phone number 3051234567. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In EVERY section you should put ONE transport

2) you should correctly setup headers, like fromuser etc. For more info ask vonage

3) you should do registration,see register =>  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You always need an account for your phone and the voice provider in sip.conf (in case you are using sip) and if you have a trunk (real world number) usually you need a register line then the  extensions.conf must have the basic dialplan for two contexts, internal-outcoming and external-incoming or internal calls between lines.

I think with the example configuration files asterisk has in etc/asterisk it would be enough but you can also check asterisk the definitive guide third edition.

Good luck!